# Theory related to choosing high-information representative samples of a distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, representative

Let $X$ be a random variable of human height and suppose that $X$ is normally distributed.

If our goal is to select 'representatives' of the concept 'height', a reasonable way to choose representative samples for $X$ is to choose those having values far from the mean. (Since $X$ is normally distributed, samples having values near mean would be not meaningful.. (less information)).

However, if $X$ is *not* bell shaped, so that it looks like a beta distribution B(0.5,0.5) [image] (which is not bell-shaped), samples having values far from the mean must not be representatives for the concept 'height'.

Is there any theory related to this? (choosing representatives)

Comment: Importance sampling is related to your question (of how to use few points to estimate a population parameter), though it's not specifically focused on identifying exemplars/prototypes of a population.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I do not get it.. Isn't importance sampling a technique used to sample from a distribution which we cannot sample from directly..?